# How would you make the random variable for this to solve the problem?

Tags: statistics, proof-writing, random-variables

Consider an ant that lives on a plane, and its home is at the origin $\left(0, 0\right)$.

- Starting at home, every second, the ant will travel a distance of $1$ in a cardinal direction (East/West/North/South, each direction with equal probability) and stop at $\left(x, y\right)$, where $x$ and $y$ are some integers.
- Let $X$ be the random variable that looks at the current location $\left(x, y\right)$ of the ant, and takes the value $1$ when
  $x + y$ is $odd$ and the value $0$ when $x + y$ is $even$.

Consider the experiment where the ant continues traveling one
point at a time until it returns home, and let $Y$ be the random variable that counts how many times the ant moved before returning home:

$\left(\mbox{a}\right)$ Show that $X$ must change values after every movement.

$\left(\mbox{b}\right)$ Use $\left(\mbox{a}\right)$ to show that $Y$ only takes positive even values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that, at a given moment, the ant is at (x, y).  At the next moment it is at (x+ 1, y) or (x- 1, y) or (x, y+ 1) or (x, y- 1).  The sum of the coordinates is either (x+ y)+ 1 or (x+ y)- 1.  If x+ y is even both x+ y+ 1 and x+ y- 1 are even x+ y+ 1 are odd and if x+ y is odd both x+ y+ 1 and x+ y- 1 are even. Since x+ y changes parity each time, X changes value each time.

At (0, 0) 0+ 0= 0 is even so X is 0 at (0, 0).  If the ant goes around a loop from (0, 0) to (0, 0), X= 0 at both beginning and end. Since X changes value, from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0, on each step, to go from 0 to 0 there must have been an even number of steps.